# Why are my elements overlapping when screen is minimized?

Tags: html, css, element, positioning, overlapping

I'm new to coding and joined TOP. Part of the process of learning to code is making a Google Homepage. It's difficult but I've progressed somewhat. My current issue is when I minimize my screen, I notice the elements overlap. I've played around with the code and it still happens.

```
.googlelogo {
  display: flex;
  padding: 7% 10% 10%;
  margin: 10% 40% 30%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.about {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 17%;
  height: 80%;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.store {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 17%;
  height: 80%;
  margin-left: 6%
}

.gmail {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 17%;
  height: 80%;
  margin-left: 82%
}

.images {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 17%;
  height: 80%;
 margin-left: 87%
_____________________________________________________________________________



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <title>Google Homepage</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="googlelogo">
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Google Logo">
</div>



<a class="about" href="https://google.com/about">About</a>
<a class="store" href="https://google.com/store">Store</a>

<a class="gmail" href="https://gmail.com">Gmail</a>
<a class="images" href="https://google.com/images">Images</a>

<div class="searchbox">
  <input type="text" name="" value="">
  <button type="search" name="button">Search</button>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

[Issue I'm having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gg1Or.png)

Comment: As sort of a best practice, I generally try to avoid absolute positioning except when absolutely necessary.  Because you are removing it from the document flow, you get _no_ help from the browser in trying to manage collisions as space gets tight.  One option to help you might be to take a look at the actual Google homepage with the developer tools to get a sense of how they have built their page and positioned their elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the changes i made was wrap the anchor element tags in a div and wrapped those divs in a section tag, then gave the section tag a styling

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <title>Google Homepage</title>
</head>
<style>
.googlelogo {
  display: flex;
  padding: 7% 10% 10%;
  margin: 10% 40% 30%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.about {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 17%;
  height: 80%;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.store {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 17%;
  height: 80%;
  margin-left: 6%
}

/* CHANGES MADE BELOW */
.itemsOnTheTop{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
/* CHANGES MADE ABOVE */

</style>
<body>
<div class="googlelogo">
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Google Logo">
</div>

<!-- CHANGES MADE BELOW -->
<section class="itemsOnTheTop">
  <div>
    <a class="" href="https://google.com/about">About</a>
    <a class="" href="https://google.com/store">Store</a>
  </div>
  
  
 
  <div>
    <a class="" href="https://gmail.com">Gmail</a>
    <a class="" href="https://google.com/images">Images</a>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- CHANGES MADE ABOVE -->



<div class="searchbox">
  <input type="text" name="" value="">
  <button type="search" name="button">Search</button>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```